# for loop skips first item in array

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get all elements in the body then remove the ones with a certain class from the array. The for loop, however, skips the first element with that class. I added some logic to add classes to the removed elements and kept elements just for visual feedback. You can run the snippet to see it.

```js
var list;
var all = [];
var newall = [];
list = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  all.push(list[i]);
}

for(var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
  if(all[j].classList.contains('div')) {
    all.splice(j, 1);
    all[j].classList.add('remove');
  } else {
    newall.push(all[j]);
    all[j].classList.add('keep');
  } 
}
```

```css
.remove {text-decoration: line-through;}

.keep {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="alpha" class="div one">
alpha
</div>
<p id="bravo" class="div two">
bravo
</p>
<div id="charlie">
charlie
</div>
```

Comment: When you *splice* a member from an array, it moves all the higher indexes down one. So if you do that in an incrementing loop, each time you splice the *i*th member, the *i* + 1 member is now *i*, so it's skipped on the next iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splice causes the members of the array to be re–indexed, so the loop skips the next member. To avoid that, iterate from the end to the start. If you want to maintain order in the result array, use *unshift* instead of *push*.

Also, you're adding the remove class after splicing the member from the array, so it get's added to the following member. So add it before splicing.

```js
var all = [];
var newall = [];
var list = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
var i = j = list.length;

while (i--) {
  all[i] = list[i];
}

while (j--) {
  
  if(all[j].classList.contains('div')) {
    // add class before removing
    all[j].classList.add('remove');
    all.splice(j, 1);
    
  } else {
    // Since iterating backwards, add members to start of newall
    // with unshift rather than end with push
    newall.unshift(all[j]);
    all[j].classList.add('keep');
  } 
}
```

```css
.remove {text-decoration: line-through;}
.keep {background: yellow;}
```

```html
<div id="alpha" class="div one">alpha</div>
<p id="bravo" class="div two">bravo</p>
<div id="charlie">charlie</div>
```

Oh, and creating *newall* seems redundant as it will contain the same members as all.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, once you splice the element the value of `j` should not be incremented.

Assuming you are removing the item in index 1(j=1) and array has a length of 3, once you splice it the array length becomes 2 and the value at index 2 is now at index 1. In the next iteration you are incrementing the value of j to 2 now the loop condition fails and the last iteration fails to execute.

```js
var list;
var all = [];
var newall = [];
list = document.body.getElementsByTagName('*');
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  all.push(list[i]);
}

for (var j = 0; j < all.length; j++) {
  if (all[j].classList.contains('div')) {
    all[j].classList.add('remove');
    all.splice(j, 1);
    j--
  } else {
    newall.push(all[j]);
    all[j].classList.add('keep');
  }
}
```

```css
.remove {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
.keep {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="alpha" class="div one">
  alpha
</div>
<p id="bravo" class="div two">
  bravo
</p>
<div id="charlie">
  charlie
</div>
```